# Can I generate a real time SSIM/PSNR plot while playing a video in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, ssim

If I have both reference and test videos and I want to play the test video while also observing a plot of SSIM or PSNR, can this be done using FFmpeg's filter?

Answer (score 0):

Basic template is

```
ffplay -f lavfi "movie='source.mp4'[s];movie='encode.mp4',split[p][e];[e][s]psnr,drawgraph=m1='lavfi.psnr.psnr_avg':min=0:max=60:slide=scroll,scale=640:-1,drawgrid=h=ih/10[g];[p][g]vstack"
```

The graph should be rescaled to the same width as the encoded video (`640` in this case).

For SSIM, use the `ssim` filter in place of `psnr`. Change `m1` to `lavfi.ssim.All` and min, max to `0` and `1` resp.

See the docs for these filters at http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html